# How to change element on different page

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, filter, local-storage

I have form on the index.html page that I would like to use as a "search" feature. The chosen option from the select box would provide the search parameter for the displayed divs on the second page.

`<button class=" col-6 btn btn-main" id="searchButton" type="submit" onclick="findHotel();" style="background-color: #ee580f;" class="form-control">Search</button>`

`<form id="tourForm" class="main-form tour-form" action="">`

So far the onclick() function for the submit button changes the action of the form to the desired url.

I would like to hide all divs on the second page that do not fit into the search criteria. This would be similar to a filter, but the parameters would be chosen from the first page, and applied on the second. The function would hide all div elements and show only the div that matches selected option.

```
function findHotel() {
    var tourType = document.getElementById("hotelLocation").value;

    switch (tourType) {
        case "Chicago, USA":
            document.getElementById("hotelForm").action = "html/book.html";
            document.getElementsByClassName("hotel-option").style.display = none;
            document.getElementById("chicagoHotel").style.display = block;
            break;

        case "Singapore":
            document.getElementById("hotelForm").action = "html/book.html";
            document.getElementsByClassName("hotel-option").hide;
            document.getElementById("singaporeHotel").
            break;

        default:
            document.getElementById("tourForm").action = "html/book.html";
            break;
    }
}
```

After trying multiple approaches, it looks like I need to use localstorage or cookies to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: You can also use the URL

Comment: You want to submit the form as a GET then read the data from the url on the other page. Then do the display change on the other page based on what you read from url

Comment: I think you can use some JSON object to store the current server and information, that will allow you to persist the information in the current state.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass values from a page to another.
If you have a backend server, POST request can be used.

If you have no backend server to support, then your only way to do it is by using GETrequest or Local Cookies only.